# How to play youtube vidoes in silverlight(in browser)?

Tags: silverlight

I want to develop an silverlight application which plays youtube videos. I dont want to let users install my silverlight application on thri PCs, so I would need to play the videos in browser. Is there anyway we can achieve this?

Comment: Could take a look at http://www.uxpassion.com/2009/08/silverlight-tutorial-play-hd-youtube-videos-silverlight/. I haven't done it myself so won't post as an answer, but there are a few results for playing the HD videos in Silverlight. I don't know if they still work though, as again, not something I've used.

Comment: Hrm, reading a bit more there (I read it when it came out) and it appears that it doesn't work anymore for some reason. I'll leave it there as perhaps a starting point to maybe be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight 4 comes with a new **WebBrowser control** which lets you display HTML content (e.g. an iframe with youtube in it). Unfortunately, that control will work in **Out-Of-Browser mode only**. So if you don't want users to install your app on their PCs, that won't be an option for you.

So the only ways I see to work around that problem are

A) Open a **popup (new browser window)** which shows youtube content.

B) Use JavaScript to open a new div/iframe on top of your Silverlight app which shows youtube. You will have to enable the so-called **windowless mode** for your Silverlight app then (otherwise, you won't be able to display any kind of HTML on top of your app).

Cheers, Alex